# Is there any way to avoid a conditional structure in this case?

Tags: android, conditional-statements

I'm starting to design an Android Application in which I need to be continuously listening for new commands and perform different actions based on the command received.

So let's see an example of what I'd like to avoid if possible:

```
Public void onCommandReceived(String command)
{
     Switch (command)
     {
        Case A:
            DoActionA();
            break;

        ...

        Case Z:
            DoActionZ();
            break;
     }
}
```

Edit:

I will receive a long string and I will have to parse the string to get the command.

Is there any nicer implementation of this problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What's the type of "command"? You could use an array or hash map of functions, so then the method just becomes a wrapper around lookup in a data structure.

Comment: Make a `Map<String, Function<T, R>> functions = new HashMap<>>();`. Lets say that each command has a name and you can use `command.getName();`

Comment: Edited question to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point you need to have a structure like your `switch (command)` example, at least in order to convert user input or program events into commands, and the humble switch statement is a good choice for this logic. There are alternatives, but the switch statement is clear and everyone knows instantly what it means.

Here are some alternatives though, which might be useful depending on the specifics of your design:

#### Decision table

You can pre-populate a `Map<>` or similar with the mapping of commands to actions, something like this:

```
Map<Command, Action> decisionTable = new HashMap<>();
decisionTable.put(A, new DoActionA());
decisionTable.put(B, new DoActionB());
```

This would be initialised somewhere once, and then called like this:

```
Public void onCommandReceived(String command)
{
    decisionTable.get(command).action();
}
```

I've left out the details, like error handling when the action is not present, the `Action` interface, and the individual classes implementing each action.

#### Virtual dispatch

If making a separate class for each action, like above, suits your design, then instead of passing a "dumb" command to your function, pass an instance of an interface. This is exactly like the decision table above, except the `Command` is the one with an interface and subclasses - you don't need to do the switch, because the command/action subclass already has that logic for you, for example:

```
interface Command {
    void action();
}

class CommandA {
    @Override
    void action() {
        // do something
    }
}

...

Public void onCommandReceived(Command command)
{
    command.action();
}
```

If you need to make different decisions based on which command *at multiple points int your code*, you might even want something as fancy as double dispatch, which I won't go into here.

#### Switch

But if this is the only pace in your code where you make a decision based on what kind of command it is, then the `switch` statement is not clever or tricky, which makes it exactly the sort of code you want to be looking at 6 months later - you and everyone else will understand it perfectly, and the value of that should not be underestimated.

Comment: Loved that answer. I'll go with that switch case structure then.

Answer (score -1):

May be this is what you are looking for

```
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
    doSomthing();
    break;
case 4:
    doAnother();
    break;
```

this will work because case 1 and 2 don't have break statements and will fall to case three .

Comment: Each case will execute different methods

Comment: @Aldridge1991- then there should be switch case or if statement for all cases